# Why do the submenu controls of my complex menu component lose focus on input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to build a menu using the MUI `Menu` component. When you click on a menu item, you would get a popup input control (such as `Autocomplete`, `TextField`, `Select`, or a custom form) depending on your menu choice. I am using `Popper` to show those controls.

The problem is that, when the controls are shown they quickly lose focus; as soon as I try to take any action (e.g. writing something in `TextField` or selecting a value in `Select`, etc.).

I am new to MUI, so I wonder if I am using the wrong components or not handing some events.

Here is my [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-autocomplete-forked-exg5ph?file=/src/index.js:0-2765)

Here is my (significantly simplified) code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  Button,
  Menu,
  MenuItem,
  Fade,
  Box,
  Popper,
  TextField
} from "@material-ui/core";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [plusAnchorEl, setPlusAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const [menuItemAnchorEl, setMenuItemAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const [menuIndex, setMenuIndex] = useState(null);

  const handlePlusClick = (event) => {
    if (event.currentTarget) {
      setPlusAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    } else {
      setPlusAnchorEl(null);
    }
  };

  const handleMenuClick = (event, index) => {
    if (event.currentTarget) {
      setMenuItemAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
      setMenuIndex(index);
    } else {
      setMenuItemAnchorEl(null);
      setMenuIndex(null);
    }
  };

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setMenuItemAnchorEl(null);
    setMenuIndex(null);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handlePlusClick}>+</Button>

      <Menu
        anchorEl={plusAnchorEl}
        open={!!plusAnchorEl}
        onClose={handleMenuClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem key="1" onClick={(e) => handleMenuClick(e, "One")}>
          One
          {menuIndex === "One" && (
            <Popper
              open={menuIndex === "One"}
              placement="right-end"
              anchorEl={menuIndex === "One" ? menuItemAnchorEl : null}
              transition
            >
              {({ TransitionProps }) => (
                <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
                  <Box>
                    <TextField />
                  </Box>
                </Fade>
              )}
            </Popper>
          )}
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem key="2" onClick={(e) => handleMenuClick(e, "Two")}>
          Two
          {menuIndex === "Two" && (
            <Popper
              open={menuIndex === "Two"}
              placement="right-end"
              anchorEl={menuIndex === "Two" ? menuItemAnchorEl : null}
              transition
            >
              {({ TransitionProps }) => (
                <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
                  <Box>
                    <TextField select>
                      <MenuItem key="2.1">Two.One</MenuItem>
                      <MenuItem key="2.2">Two.Two</MenuItem>
                    </TextField>
                  </Box>
                </Fade>
              )}
            </Popper>
          )}
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Where should the `TextField` be rendered? inside relative `MenuItem` or outside the `Menu`?

Comment: Outside, e.g. to the right of MenuItem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue looks like it's caused by the fact that the `Popper` components are inside the `MenuItem` components. When you click on the `TextField` or `Select` inside the `Popper`, the `Menu`'s click-away listener triggers, causing the menu to close and the `Popper` to lose focus.
To solve this, you can move the `Popper` components outside of the `Menu` component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  Button,
  Menu,
  MenuItem,
  Fade,
  Box,
  Popper,
  TextField
} from "@material-ui/core";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [plusAnchorEl, setPlusAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const [menuItemAnchorEl, setMenuItemAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const [menuIndex, setMenuIndex] = useState(null);

  const handlePlusClick = (event) => {
    if (event.currentTarget) {
      setPlusAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    } else {
      setPlusAnchorEl(null);
    }
  };

  const handleMenuClick = (event, index) => {
    if (event.currentTarget) {
      setMenuItemAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
      setMenuIndex(index);
    } else {
      setMenuItemAnchorEl(null);
      setMenuIndex(null);
    }
  };

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setMenuItemAnchorEl(null);
    setMenuIndex(null);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handlePlusClick}>+</Button>

      <Menu
        anchorEl={plusAnchorEl}
        open={!!plusAnchorEl}
        onClose={handleMenuClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem key="1" onClick={(e) => handleMenuClick(e, "One")}>
          One
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem key="2" onClick={(e) => handleMenuClick(e, "Two")}>
          Two
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>

      {menuIndex === "One" && (
        <Popper
          open={menuIndex === "One"}
          placement="right-end"
          anchorEl={menuItemAnchorEl}
          transition
        >
          {({ TransitionProps }) => (
            <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
              <Box>
                <TextField />
              </Box>
            </Fade>
          )}
        </Popper>
      )}

      {menuIndex === "Two" && (
        <Popper
          open={menuIndex === "Two"}
          placement="right-end"
          anchorEl={menuItemAnchorEl}
          transition
        >
          {({ TransitionProps }) => (
            <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
              <Box>
                <TextField select>
                  <MenuItem key="2.1">Two.One</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem key="2.2">Two.Two</MenuItem>
                </TextField>
              </Box>
            </Fade>
          )}
        </Popper>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Tvm! It works for my real code (getting some other odd problems with forms being all over the screen now, but maybe unrelated)